# React JS: Unable to display array data onClick

Tags: arrays, reactjs

In the console i can see the object inside the array on click every time.

But I am unable to display it

I tried map() instead of forEach, and it shows the item just once.

I need it to show each time i click the button

Can someone tell me what I am doing Wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isClicked : false
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      isClicked : true
    }) 
  }

  render() {
    let myarray = [ ]

    let myobject = {
      color: 'blue',
      shape: 'round'
    }

    myarray.push(myobject)

    let looped = myarray.forEach((data) => <><h1>{data.color}</h1> <h1>{data.shape}</h1></>)

    console.log(myarray)
   return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
        { this.state.isClicked ? looped : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want the object to display on the page when I click the button

Comment: read what foreach returns

Comment: in your case try using map instead

Comment: if i console log the array it shows and myarray with myobject inside it just like i would want. now i want to display the items of my object, and it isnt showing

Comment: `forEach` returns `undefined` so your `looped` is set to `undefined`. Use the `.map` method instead of `forEach`

Comment: I tried map() instead of forEach, and it shows the item just once. and not on every click

Comment: You not changing state on every click? why it should show it more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your snippet:

1. [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) has no return value.
2. on `handleClick` you change state to `isClicked: true` once.

In order to fix your code and display your data on every click you should:

1. Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each object to `React.Element`.
2. Change the state on every button click, so in your case, on every click, you should reverse the boolean value of `this.state.isClicked`.

Here is a working example:

```js
import React from 'react';

const myArray = [
  {
    color: 'blue',
    shape: 'round'
  }
];

const looped = myArray.map((data, i) => (
  <div key={i}>
    <h1>{data.color}</h1> <h1>{data.shape}</h1>
  </div>
));

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isClicked: false
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      console.log(prevState);
      return { isClicked: !prevState.isClicked };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
        {this.state.isClicked && looped}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57233877-ClickExample]

Comment: thanks a lot for you example man! but its actually a toggle that you made. Imagine if you have a form and on clicking submit a div displays with the input values and that happens everytime you click a new div displays with those values, thats what i was trying to accomplish with a simple array

Comment: I answered about what you asked, for other case you should ask another question.